# Is there a way of listing the elements that makes a real fact fun?

Tags: style, technique

For instance I wrote this thing that is real

> God’s love is like your parents love /
>   except for the ‘‘burning, crying, and
>   screaming for eternity in hell" part
>   / if you don’t obey them.

and funny (well that's arguable).

Is there a way of listing the elements that makes a real fact, fun?

(Well I'm trying to add humour but the main point of these writings is to tell my feelings and have social impact).

**EDIT**

By elements I mean the connection between words or literary tools.

Comment: What "elements" are you talking about?

Comment: @Ralph Gallagher OK I edited the questions.

Comment: Sorry, that's your job as a writer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Read a book on writing stand up comedy. They'll help you with this, as a major factor in stand up com is that you're the sole speaker: The narrator, as it were, of whatever you find you need to tell and channel through amusing the listeners (often with stories or the like).

Now for some useful stuff:

I'd listen a bit to George Carlin or other such comedians you might find funny, and take what there is to be grasped from them. I'd not be able to explain how to do it, but that particular theme you're touching was addressed by Carlin in one of his shows. If memory doesn't fail me now, the lines were similar to this:

> God is all powerful and watches every movement every person does undertake, ever. He has these ten little things he'd like you to do, or else he'll send you to a place of eternal pain, suffering and torment and you will never die. But He loves you. Yes, He loves you and He need your money

It is but a matter of finding the most ridiculous way of putting things, in some cases. In others, a matter of self deprecation, or smartly talking about "bad things that happened". It'll depend on what you need to say.